# How to send JSON data from salesforce into Pusher channel?

Tags: apex, json

I have this Apex Pusher Class that can accept a channel, event, message

```
public class Pusher {
    public class PusherException extends Exception {
    }

    String authKey;
    String authSecret;
    String appid;

    public Pusher(String authKey, String authSecret, String appid) {
        this.authKey = authKey;
        this.authSecret = authSecret;
        this.appid = appid;
    }

    public void push(String channel, String name, String message) {
        String authTimestamp = String.valueOf(Datetime.now().getTime() / 1000);
        String authVersion = '1.0';
        String bodyMd5 = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(Crypto.generateDigest('MD5', 
          Blob.valueOf(message)));
        String path = '/apps/'+appid+'/channels/'+channel+'/events';

        String stringToSign = 'POSTn'+path+'nauth_key='+authKey+
            '&auth_timestamp='+authTimestamp+'&auth_version='+authVersion+
            '&body_md5='+bodyMd5+'&name='+name;

        String authSignature =
            EncodingUtil.convertToHex(Crypto.generateMac('hmacSHA256',
              Blob.valueOf(stringToSign), Blob.valueOf(authSecret)));

        String endpoint = 'https://api.pusherapp.com'+path+
            '?auth_key='+authKey+
            '&auth_timestamp='+authTimestamp+
            '&auth_version='+authVersion+
            '&body_md5='+bodyMd5+
            '&name='+name+
            '&auth_signature='+authSignature;

        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(); 

        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
        req.setBody(message);    

        Http http = new Http();

        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);

        if (res.getStatusCode() != 202) {
            throw new PusherException(res.getStatusCode() + ' ' + res.getStatus());
        }


    }

}
```

And I'm trying to invoke the Pusher Class and send data to my pusher channel via...

```
Pusher myPusher = new Pusher('APP_KEY', 'APP_SECRET','APP_ID');
myPusher.push('test_channel', 'my_event', '{"message": "hello"}');
```

But there's an error in the data format/type.

Comment: Hi Ivan, can you specify the error that appears?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the entire error message that you're getting (don't paraphrase!) as well as the stack trace.

Comment: I have this error message. https://prnt.sc/p6qi19 . And btw, I'm following this blog from 2011 https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2011/10/publishing-real-time-updates-from-apex-with-pusher.html

Comment: @Ivan Please [edit] your post to include the details in the body.

Comment: `400 bad request` fixes can be found [here](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/400-bad-request/). My suggestion is to debug this with Postman, iterating until you get past the 400, then modify the apex code accordingly.  This way you'll be debugging against the Pusher API (only)